# 断ち切るように言葉がきっぱりして適切なこと

Tags: meaning, words

> 断ち切るように言葉がきっぱりして適切なこと。

Does this mean word like '断ち切る' is relevant to きっぱりして?

I know that 断ち切る modifies きっぱりする but I don't get the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: I changed the title of your post because it would probably be overlooked the way it was since direct translation requests are off-topic here.  So since this question shows knowledge and effort, I didn't want it to go overlooked.

Comment: I would not call that a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this a word definition in some dictionary?

断ち切るように and きっぱり both mean *clearly*, *unambiguously*, *decisively*, etc. In English you can say *clear-cut*, too.

I don't think 断ち切るように modifies きっぱりする. This 断ち切るように adverbially modifies 言葉がきっぱりして適切な as a whole.

> 断ち切るように言葉がきっぱりして適切なこと
>   (lit.) *for words to be clear and adequate as if it were sharply cut.*
>   *using words clearly and adequately.*

Comment: this sentence : 言葉がきっぱりして適切なことexplain 断ち切る？ -> 言葉がきっぱりして適切なこと->it doesnt mean : it is adequate (適切なこと)to make words to be clear (言葉がきっぱりして)/for words to be clear and adequate(？)

Comment: I said "断ち切るように modifies 言葉がきっぱりして適切な", not the other way around. And where did you see this "sentence" in the first place? This is not a full sentence but a noun phrase. This sentence does not say some concrete thing is good or bad, but it describes the definition of some word.